Should I use a banner in Android with Material 3?
We use the Google Maps SDK. We want to use an icon inside of a Snackbar to make it easier for a user to grasp that internet connection is missing, or that he needs to zoom in, for using a feature. When checking the M3 guidelines, they state we should not add an icon but consider a banner (or a dialog which would not make sense, as the user needs to be able to pinch).
However in the guidelines there is no banner component. Should I still use banners in M3? If so in which cases?
Material 3 Guidelines
For now we just added an icon to the Snackbar.
